# Dumbed-Down python fix for missing module

Tags: python

I have a simple Python 3 program that I have been using once-per-week for years to scrape a few web pages and dump some text output.  It uses beautifulsoup4 and requests to get its job done.  Literally all I've ever done is double click the .PY file (or run it from the commannd line), let it run and then edit the resulting output text file.

But lately, it stopped working.  It can't find beautifulsoup4.

```
D:\Dev\Srr>srr_new6.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dev\Srr\srr_new6.py", line 23, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

The program has not changed.  Back when I first "installed" it, all I had to do was this:

1. Install Python for Windows
2. Open a command prompt
3. pip install beautifulsoup4
4. pip install requests

Once I'd done that, I could either double-click it or run it from the command line and it would just work.

So when this happened, the first thing I tried was to start over.  Uninstalled python.  Reinstall the latest (3.6).  Ran these steps again.  But nope, still doesn't work.  I still get the bs4 not found message.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.192]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>d:

D:\>cd dev\srr

D:\Dev\Srr>srr_new6.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dev\Srr\srr_new6.py", line 23, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

OK, bs4 not found.  Try installing the packages...

```
D:\Dev\Srr>pip install beautifulsoup4
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages

D:\Dev\Srr>pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\joe\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\joe\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in c:\users\joe\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from requests)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in 
c:\users\joe\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from requests)

D:\Dev\Srr>srr_new6.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dev\Srr\srr_new6.py", line 23, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named bs4

D:\Dev\Srr>
```

I even tried using the --no-cache-dir option of pip.  No difference:

Can anyone see anything in these messages which might explain the problem?  Or perhaps give me a simple set of steps that would let me get back to where I was?  I don't develop in Python (and sadly, I just don't have the time or energy to learn).  I just want to make this one program work.  I can run as admin on my box no problem.  I don't care if I end up setting the environment for every python program on the machine.  This is the only thing I use python for

A little background:

Here are the first dozen or so statements of the program, including the attempts to import.  None of this code has changed in years.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

# -----------------------------------------------------------------
#                            PACKAGES
# -----------------------------------------------------------------

# Python Packages that must be installed

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

try:
    from dateutil import parser as dateparser
except:
    pass

# Standard Python Packages
import re
import argparse
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import sys
import logging
from io import open

# ... rest of the program...
```

Any guidance appreciated.